# Python namespaced xml-parsing error

Tags: python

What's wrong with the following code? I am expecting boogie as output.

```
import urllib.request
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

html = '''<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"
 xmlns:enc="http://purl.oclc.org/net/rss_2.0/enc#"
><foo><title>boogie</title></foo></rdf:RDF>'''

root = ET.fromstring(html)
ns = { 'default': 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/', 'rdf': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'}

titles = root.findall("default:.//title", ns)
[print(title.text) for title in titles]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib.request
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

html = '''<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"
 xmlns:enc="http://purl.oclc.org/net/rss_2.0/enc#"
 ><foo><title>boogie</title></foo></rdf:RDF>'''

root = ET.fromstring(html)
ns = '{http://purl.org/rss/1.0/}'

titles = root.findall(".//%stitle" % ns)
print titles[0].text
```

This is working version

Comment: you can change this line: `titles = root.findall("default:.//title", ns)`
to `titles = root.findall(".//default:title", ns)` then it will work. You put `default` in wrong place